# Windows 10 WebView and Adobe Flash

Tags: windows, flash, webview, adobe, universal

The new Microsoft Edge browser has built-in support for Adobe Flash.  The updated WebView control in the Windows 10 SDK utilizes Microsoft Edge as its engine.

I am trying to figure out how to enable the WebView control to render Adobe Flash content from a website in a Universal Windows App (either a Hosted Web App or a Packaged Web App).

Any ideas or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable flash in webview on UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355786/how-to-enable-flash-in-webview-on-uwp)

Answer (score 2):

WebView doesn't use Edge as the engine but uses IE11. Quote from the docs - "WebView always uses Internet Explorer 11 in document mode".

It also doesn't support any plugins or such, which would include Flash.

Full run of caveats from the control doc:

> It does not support any ActiveX controls or plugins like Microsoft
>   Silverlight or Portable Document Format (PDF) files. Additionally,
>   WebView does not support some HTML5 features including AppCache,
>   IndexedDB, programmatic access to the Clipboard, and geolocation.

More "tidbit" reading up at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx .

Enjoy.  Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa.

Answer (score 1):

On Universal application, the webview is using edge now but it does not change anything regarding plugins.

Here is what it says from  the MSDN :

> In apps compiled for *Windows 10, WebView uses the Microsoft Edge*
>   rendering engine to display HTML content. In apps compiled for Windows
>   8 or Windows 8.1, WebView uses Internet Explorer 11 in document mode.
>   It does not support any ActiveX controls or plugins like Microsoft
>   Silverlight or Portable Document Format (PDF) files.

Comment: So basically if I do webview.navigate('aa.pdf') it will not work in Windows 10?