# How to enable flash in webview on UWP?

Tags: uwp

I used a `WebView` to browse a url, but it needs flash.

I tried

```
WebViewSettings ws = webView.Settings;
ws.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

But javascript has nothing relate with flash plugin.

Is there any way to enable it on uwp?

Comment: Flash in insecure tech. Why are you trying to achieve it working?

Comment: @ad1Dima Some video sites still need flash

Comment: not always necessary to have flash, to play flash video ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash is not supported in UWP WebView.

> In apps compiled for Windows 10, WebView uses the Microsoft Edge rendering engine to display HTML content. In apps compiled for Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, WebView uses Internet Explorer 11 in document mode. It does not support any Microsoft ActiveX controls **or plugins** like Microsoft Silverlight or Portable Document Format (PDF) files.

Source: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView).

See also this [MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/10/18/ten-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview/#AN3), as this confirms the statement.

> WebView doesn’t do Flash.  Or Silverlight.  Or PDF.  Or any other ActiveX control or plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, if you want to play flash video in UWP app, you don't need Flash.

VLC can play RTPM stream that used in flash video. So, if you have rtpm links you can play this video in UWP App.

I'm my case I used [VLC.MediaElement](https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement). You can simply add it using NuGet. Than you can simply use it like:

```
<vlc:MediaElement Source="rtmp://example.com/video_720p" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" HardwareAcceleration="True"/>
```